# Using VS 2022 to open SSIS packages created in VS 2019

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, visual-studio-2022

I have used Visual Studio 2019 to maintain about 50 SSIS packages of various complexity.  I recently started using VS 2022, but am having issues opening these older packages.  For reference, I am running VS Pro v17.6.5, with the "SQL Server Integration Services Projects 2022" extension v1.1 installed.

When I try to open even the simplest project in 2022, I get errors like this:

Error loading 'MyPackage.dtsx' : The package failed to load due to error 0xC0010014 "One or more error occurred. There should be more specific errors preceding this one that explains the details of the errors. This message is used as a return value from functions that encounter errors.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.

All of my projects use the "package deployment model", and are not Azure enabled.  If I start a brand new SSIS project, it works without issues.

I would appreciate any suggestions on this frustrating issue.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

being on a same situation but a different problem to be solve later, i'll layout a bit to establish common grounds:

**OS:** Windows Server 2019

**SSMS version:** SQL Server 2017

**VS IDE version:**
**VS 2017 Pro** +SSDT+SSIS ,
Side-by-Side VS2022 Community+SSIS for testing purposes prior to full migration.

Since you and my Env. Settings could be different, let assume these as follows:

- DB **and** SSIS project solutions are configured to run in 32-bit
  only
- DTSX(s) contains OLEDB source/destinations and/or excel source/destinations
- DTSX(s) contains script tasks
- existing SSIS solutions have N amount of DTSX projects created in VS2017 in 32bit env.

when first opening the SSIS solution directly in vs2022, my case was it marked 2 out of 2 projects in my solution as "unsupported". however, on right-click > reload, the project actually refreshed and can be accessed properly.

there is a few things that might warrant a double check before proceeding:

- is the project property of Run64bitRuntime set to **False**?
- is the 32bit AccessDataBaseEngine (Microsoft Access Database engine
  2010) used for the ACE12.0 (commonly used for excel
  source/destination)?
- is there any script task components that is **not** supported in 64 bit **only** environment?
- is there any DLL dependencies

limited by Company policies wren't able to provide screenshots for examples but above are what i've covered for the weeks to assess if a migration of direct uninstall vs2017 then swap to vs2022 is possible(which is definitely a no). i'll continue edit the answer or add in comments for further findings to refine the answers.